# Standardize/Normalize data (binary+numeric) before autoencoder, ward hierarchy clustering, etc.?

Tags: deep-learning, cluster-analysis, normalization, hierarchy, standardized

I have a dataset with both binary data (0,1) and numeric data with different units. If I want to apply some machine learning techniques to classify my data (potentially autoencoder or hierarchy clustering), should I standardize or normalize the data?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

For neural networks you may want to standardize continuous variables for numerical reasons. But it depends on your platform. Consider Googles TPUs: they work with 1 byte precision, so you want the relevant input domain to use this limited range optimally.

For distance based methods like clustering, preprocessing the data is crucial, but difficult. It is false that standardizing is always the right thing to do. But it is fairly common to apply some normalization. But you need a domain expert to find the best normalization.